# Not reflect my changes in `$rootScope` in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

I'm having trouble trying to reflect my changes in `$rootScope`. As I understand (please note that I'm very new to `angular`), `$rootScope` is visible across `controllers`. What I'm trying to do is to update a value in `$rootScope` and trying to read that value in my `html` page.

The problem is even though the changes are applied to `$rootScope` its not reflecting in my view. Following is the code

I have a `div` which I want to show/hide depending on the value

```
#view
<div ng-hide="{{logged}}">
  // this should visible only if the logged is true
</div>  



#controller1 I set the rootscope to false
$rootScope.logged = false; // this makes the view hidden


#controller2 I set the rootScope to true
$rootScope.logged = true; 
$rootScope.$apply();
```

But making the `$rootScope.logged = true` doesn't make the view visible. My questions are

1 - What I might be going wrong?

2 - What is the most Angular way of doing such a thing?

Comment: `ng-hide="logged"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `{{` in your html template.

```
#view
<div ng-hide="logged">
  // this should visible only if the logged is true
</div>
```

This is enough.

Comment: thanks it works, and I could removed the `$rootScope.$apply()` as well, all good now :)

Comment: You only need to use $apply if you are updating out of the angular context (if my knowledge serves correct) e.g jquery, if you're in a scope object you shouldn't need to call apply